# Problem while trying to run .exe on remote with psexec (c#)?

Tags: c#, exe, psexec

Hey all,
I'm trying to run an exe file ON A REMOTE MACHINE (not from, but ON).

I have very simple code as following:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
info.FileName = "psexec \\\\" + machine.Name + "\\C\\Program Files\\test.exe";
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

When trying to run this code i get "The system cannot find the file specified" error.

1. There is a file named "test.bat" on the specified directory.
2. The remote machine is on the same domain and the C folder is shared (I'm the admin).
3. I have PsTools installed and configured as environment variables.
4. I have tried variety of codes (for example if i don't use "psexec" on the ProcessStartInfo constructor and on the FileName property, the bat file runs on the local machine instead of the remote one...) and nothing works!

any ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to get it working when you run psexec from the command line? That's the first thing to try, I suspect.

Comment: Um, is it not because you're missing a colon in "\\C\\Program Files\\test.exe"?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's failing to find `psexec`, because you've set UseShellExecute to false. Try giving the full path to psexec.exe.

You should also set the `FileName` property to *just* the file you want to start, and the `Arguments` property to the command line arguments, like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
info.FileName = @"c:\whatever\psexec.exe";
info.Arguments = @"""\\" + machine.Name + @"\C\Program Files\test.exe""";
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

Note that I've *also* added double quotes in the `Arguments` property so that it doesn't get split into two arguments due to "Program Files" having a space in it.

Comment: Well, i'm kind of new to this site, so i have posted my answer up :\

Comment: @Amit Mark the answer as well, the answer if you are satisfied with it by clicking on the "tick" below the arrow.